# Wordpress Filter - Get Username

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a plugin that gives me the option to customize a specific sentence through wordpress filter.

This is the orginal code:

```
add_filter('filter_stamper_text_after_replacing_tags', 'customize_text_to_stamp', 10, 2);

function customize_text_to_stamp ($text_to_stamp, $additional_params) 
{

    $text_to_stamp .= "Adding this test message to the stamping test";

    return $text_to_stamp;
}
```

I need to insert current-username in the $text_to_stamp, so it returns like:

```
$text_to_stamp .= "Some text here" . Current-Username. "some text here";
```

This sentence is only displayed if there is a logged in user, so this verification is not necessary.

I dont know how to get the current username and how to insert it into the sentence.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code that will help you.

```
add_filter('filter_stamper_text_after_replacing_tags', 'customize_text_to_stamp', 10, 2);

function customize_text_to_stamp ($text_to_stamp, $additional_params) 
{

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    // Which you want to dispaly you can set below type
    
    // $current_user->first_name   //First Name of login User
    // $current_user->last_name    //Last Name of login User
    // $current_user->display_name // Display name of login User

    $text_to_stamp .= "Some text here" . $current_user->user_login . "some text here";

    return $text_to_stamp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('filter_stamper_text_after_replacing_tags','customize_text_to_stamp', 10, 2);

function customize_text_to_stamp ($text_to_stamp, $additional_params) 
{
   if (is_user_logged_in()){
   $current_user_name=wp_get_current_user()->user_login; 
   $text_to_stamp .= "Some text here" . esc_html($current_user_name). "some text 
    here";
  }else{
       $text_to_stamp .= "Adding this test message to the stamping test";
    }

return $text_to_stamp;
}
```